# responsive filemanager upload above public

Tags: php, responsive-filemanager

I'm trying to implement responsive filemanager in a secured environment where it's user have to login to access a file library.
To make sure users only have access to the uploaded files when the login session is active I've placed the filemanagers uploadfolder above the public_html.

```
$config = array(
/*
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
| DON'T TOUCH (base url (only domain) of site).
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
| without final / (DON'T TOUCH)
*/
'base_url' => ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ! in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']), array( 'off', 'no' ))) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],

/*
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
| path from base_url to base of upload folder
|-------------------------------------------------------------------
| with start and final /
*/
'upload_dir' => '/../Uploads/content/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| relative path from filemanager folder to upload folder
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| with final /
*/
'current_path' => '../../../../Uploads/content/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| relative path from filemanager folder to thumbs folder
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| with final /
| DO NOT put inside upload folder
*/
'thumbs_base_path' => '../../../../Uploads/thumbs/',
```

When making use of the above configurations I keep getting the error below:

> There is an error! The upload folder there isn't. Check your config.php file.

The structure of the application is as following:

-Uplevel from public

--httpdocs (public_html)

---myapplication

----admin

-----Libs

-------Filemanager directory

Please keep in mind that the uplevel contains a "uploads" directory which is the upload folder.

Is it even possible to have the upload folder above the public_html?
I tried different paths, also to set server path as base_path but still no results.

Would be great if you could help me to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Have you dumped absolute( or relative) path of folder where you are trying to move your uploaded file ? can you past it here ?

Comment: Hi Armen, Thanks for your reply. Following the absolute serverpath to an image : /var/www/vhosts/myapplication/Uploads/content/news/Efteling2.png

Comment: ok so that path fore sure exists and writable yes ? and via which command you are going to write there. will be good if you can update you question with peace of code of uploader php part

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it is possible to set the upload folder higher than your actual running script. But you haven't shown the code which triggers your error message, so it's probably being a guess show here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go from `Filemanager directory` to `Uplevel` is 5 levels up.

```
'upload_dir' => '../../../../../Uploads/content/',
'current_path' => '../../../../../Uploads/content/',
'thumbs_base_path' => '../../../../../Uploads/thumbs/',
```

Be sure the `content` and `thumbs` folders are created in `Uploads` and have write permissions.

Now when you dump the path to an image, the `Uploads` folder is not outside `public_html` but inside `myapplication`.. then the paths should be

```
'upload_dir' => '../../../Uploads/content/',
'current_path' => '../../../Uploads/content/',
'thumbs_base_path' => '../../../Uploads/thumbs/',
```

Comment: Great, what exactly was the problem?

Comment: I've reset the base_url path to the absolute server path. And everything seems to be working correctly now.